# Separate Multiple Touch inputs to seperate click events

Tags: c#, winforms, multi-touch

I have a Windows form application written in C# intended for use on desktops running either Windows 7 or 10 with multiple touch screens connected. By default I'm finding that using the touch screens acts very similarly to using the mouse which is desired behaviour. However I would like to make it so that each touch input to this application act as its own cursor. In other words, if a user touches a button I don't want the mouse to be pulled from what it was doing. Also if multiple touch or click inputs happen at the same time I want all such inputs to get processed.

is there a way to do this?

EDIT 4/15/16

I managed to find some code that may let me separate touch inputs from eachother at
http://touchswipe-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FennecUI/WMTouchForm.cs
but it only handles touches to the form itself. If a user touches a control the code will not receive any messages thus I still can't operate multiple controls at once.

Using the code at the link i have some questions.
1)Are controls belonging to the TouchForm also receiving the WM_Touch messages or do I have to register the controls as well?
2)Is there a way for the Form to listen to these messages or would I have to write a custom variant of each control on the form to either pass the message back up or handle it themselves?
3)Using this code touch events will still pull the mouse away. can this be disabled?